# Почему в .Net много запечатаных классов?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, дизайн-языка

По каким причинам большинство .net классов являются запечатанными (например: Int32, Double, String и т. п.)?

Есть ли в каких книгах/статьях объяснение данного архитектурного решения от создателей платформы?

Comment: В [.NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/#peanut-butter) запечатали более 2300 классов в целях повышения производительности.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Все классы, которые не поддерживают наследование от них, должны быть `sealed`. Чтобы класс поддерживал наследование от него, необходимо обдуманное архитектурное решение: нужно рассмотреть реальные сценарии, когда это требуется; продумать, какие члена будут перегружаться; как остальные части системы будут работать с унаследованными классами и так далее.

Если все классы сначала делать незапечатанными, а потом думать, то велика вероятность, что от этого будет больше вреда, чем пользы: никакие реальные возможности добавлены не будут, программисты полезут в потроха класса и нагромоздят хаков. И все эти хаки придётся поддерживать, потому что обратная совместимость — это святое. Это значит, что реализация может быть закрыта для улучшений в будущих версиях.

Если какой-то класс закрыт, это значит, что архитектор не нашёл нормальных сценариев наследования, которые оправдывали бы незапечатенность класса.

Классы типа `String` и `StringBuilder` закрыты, потому что это открывает возможности для изменения реализации классов, производительность которых критична для системы. Например, раньше билдер работал по принципу `List<char>`, теперь он реализован через связный список блоков, каждый из которых растёт как `List<char>`. Если бы хоть одна деталь старой реализации просочилась в `protected` интерфейс, изменить её было бы невозможно. Если бы внутренняя реализация была закрыта, то наследование было бы абсолютно бесполезно: все операции и так были бы публичными. В этом случае достаточно статических методов (в том числе extension методов).

Что касается `Int32` и `Double`, то это вообще-то структуры, они вообще не поддерживают наследование.

Логика разработчиков .NET описана в книге **Framework Design Guidelines**. Некоторые части книги [доступны на MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/).

---

На этот вопрос отвечал Эрик Липперт в статье [Why Are So Many Of The Framework Classes Sealed?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150921164345/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/22/61803.aspx) Он называет один ключевой принцип: "Хороший код делает ровно то, для чего он создан, ни больше ни меньше", а затем раскрывает его:

1. Философский. Наследование основано на отношении is-a. Если нельзя придумать такой класс, то наследование запрещено.
2. Практический. Создавать классы, которые можно расширять, сложно.
3. Совместимость. Закрытый класс можно сделать открытым, но не наоборот.
4. Безопасность. Если с помощью наследования можно переопределить логику базового класса, можно исковеркать логику и подвергнуть систему угрозе.

Более развёрнутая аргументация по ссылке выше.

---

В целом, классы во фреймворке "по умолчанию" закрыты примерно по той же причине, почему методы в C# по умолчанию невиртуальны. Можно вспомнить Java с виртуальными по умолчанию методами и учиться на ошибках.

Comment: С каких это пор: наследование == потроха наружу?

Comment: @cpp_user Чем больше возможностей для изменения логики класса и доступа к реализации класса, тем больше потрохов наружу и тем сложнее менять реализацию в будущем, не поломав обратную совместимость. С одной стороны закрытый класс, с другой — с только публичными виртуальными членами, всегда ищется компромисс. Что считать потрохами — вопрос терминологии. В любом случае `public` + `protected` > `public`.

Comment: Это проблемы разработчиков .NET думать об обратной совместимости, а не пользователей. Так что аргумент в стиле "это сложно, нужно думать, а вдруг что то сломается в будущем" очень слабый.

Comment: @cpp_user: Классов в .NET Fx очень много. Разработчики о некоторых из них думают, но, понятно, не успевают подумать обо _всех_. В этой ситуации лучше сделать тип запечатанным, чем потом кусать локти.

Comment: @cpp_user: Причём кусать локти придётся в основном программистам, у которых будет всё неправильно работать, а не разработчикам фреймворка. Качество > фичи.

Comment: А сейчас типа скомпилировал и все правильно работает ;-)

Comment: @cpp_user: Ну да. На самом деле, есть очень много инвариантов, не выразимых через наследование. Если юзер создаёт подкласс, и не выдерживает инвариант, мой код более не может на него полагаться. Кто будет таким образом ответственен за баги?

Comment: @cpp_user: Например, экземпляры класса `string` не меняются без рефлексии. Поэтому я как разработчик фреймворка могу быть уверен, что если я проверил один раз строку с credentials, то мне не нужно перепроверять её второй раз. Если бы тип `string` был бы не sealed, то злонамеренный пользователь мог бы создать унаследованный класс с хитрым поведением, и обошёл бы всю безопасность.

Comment: Создай себе security_string, а пользователям оставь обычный string. В чем проблема?

Comment: @cpp_user Вы бы лучше назвали хотя бы одну причину наследоваться от класса `String`. После этого уже можно обсуждать плюсы и минусы разных подходов. А пока требования на уровне "хочу незакрытый класс, потому что закрытые классы — отстой!"

Comment: А вы что думаете что String в .NET такой мега универсальный? В С++ например своих строк вагон и маленькая тележка на любой вкус и цвет.

Comment: @cpp_user Ага, и в каждом фреймворке-библиотеке свой класс, все они несовместимы, и их надо преобразовывать туда-сюда, чтобы "строка" из одной библиотеки скушала "строку" из другой библиотеки. Не спорю, есть плюсы, но почти в любом приложении пользуются одним типом строки, который прилагается к их основному фреймворку. Вот в .NET и сделали два класса: неизменяемый `String`, изменяемый `StringBuilder`. Они покрывают 99% случаев и достаточно эффективны в 99% случаев. Для остальных случаев можете писать свои классы, но при передаче во фреймворк преобразуйте в стандартный. Зачем наследование-то?

Comment: Глупости же, будет у вас base_string совместимый между всеми библиотеками во всем фреймворке, остальные навороты в наследуемых от base_string классах которые могут специфически использоваться в каждой конкретной библиотеке.

Comment: @cpp_user Давно `QString` из Qt, `WideString` и `AnsiString` из VCL и прочие классы строк наследуются от `basic_string<charT>`? Научите, как правильно наследоваться?

Comment: Я ж не прошу чтобы строки из .NET были совместимые с Java строками. ;-)

Comment: @cpp_user Все перечисленные выше классы написаны на C++, но почему-то не пользуются базовым типом строк из стандартной библиотеки. При чём тут джава? Вопрос интеропа мы ещё не поднимали.

Comment: Компании которые делали Qt и VCL старше чем std::string (к тому же используют свои менеджеры памяти для оптимизации строк), сейчас же многие C++ библиотеки уже поддерживают std::string без проблем, но С++ это не фреймворк и заставить всех его использовать он не может в отличии от .NET

Comment: в дотнете кстати  System.Security.SecureString есть. который не наследуется от string. и покрывает оставшийся 1%

Comment: @PashaPash: И как он совместим с обычным String?

Comment: @cpp_user а никак - это не строка вообще.

Comment: @cpp_user в .net string - неизменяемый. предположим, от него можно наследовать. приведите конкретный пример - что бы вы могли дописать в наследник (новые методы и так можно навесить, через расширения)

Comment: @PashaPash: "Маэмо те що маэмо" ;-)

Comment: @cpp_user неизменяемый - в смысле, "любая операция создает копию". а не sealed. ну свойства можно было бы в наследник дописать, которые что-то высчитывали из существующих (вот просто потому что метод вместо свойства - это некрасиво). больше ничего на ум не приходит.

Comment: Если например хранить строку изначально в какой то своей кодировке или если я хочу по 10 байт на символ или хочу чтобы строка хранилась в виде дерева в памяти.

Comment: @cpp_user Замечательно. А теперь опишите, каким образом ваша строка будет взаимодействовать с окружающим миром. Например, я хочу сравнить вашу строку со своей на равенство — кто, что и куда должен преобразовывать? Например, я хочу проверить пароль на равенство — кто и как мне будет гарантировать безопасность? Например, я хочу эффективный интероп и хочу получить терминированную нулём последовательность символов — кто и как мне его даст?

Comment: @cpp_user Например, я пишу алгоритм на строках — кто и как мне сообщит сложность каждой операции? Например, я пишу компилятор и хочу поместить данные константной строки в неизменяемую секцию данных — кто и как мне эти данные предоставит, а также сообщит, как по ним снова построить строку? И ещё тысяча вопросов. Вы придумали абстрактные примеры и совершенно не продумали, чего вы хотите достичь и как.

Comment: А кто вам сейчас что гарантирует? Строка конвертируется к базовой строке, если нужно.

Comment: @cpp_user Сейчас существование единого неизменяемого и ненаследуемого класса `String` всё гарантирует. / Ну так и сделайте свой класс `CoolString` с методом `ToString()` — что вас останавливает? Зачем наследование? Сейчас класс `StringBuilder` ("изменяемая строка") так и реализован.

Comment: Это все костыли, потому что нужно будет взять на себя все тяготы по интеграции с обычными строками.

Comment: @cpp_user У вас пока требования на уровне "хочу того, не знаю чего". Вы не придумали реальный случай, вы не продумали архитектуру, вы не привели успешных примеров подобной архитектуры. При этом вы хотите, чтобы разработчики фреймворка решили все ваши неизвестные проблемы способом, который вам нравится по неизвестной причине (наследование). Самый простой способ множественных классов строк, которого хватило для реализации изменяемых строк в дотнете, вы безапелляционно отвергаете как "костыль". Обсуждать вообще нечего.

Comment: Такие задачи ессно что все еще решаются на C++ и понятно что от .NET многого никто не ждет - все знают границы его возможностей и применимости. ;-)

Comment: @cpp_user Как я уже говорил, я не вижу "решённой проблемы" в плюсах. Там из-за зоопарка классов строк одни проблемы.

Comment: @Discord: Жги еще, десятки тысяч библиотек на С++ и неограниченные возможности по работе со строками в любом виде без каких либо ограничений.

Comment: @cpp_user Ага. Космические корабли бороздят просторы Вселенной. Но вы так и не рассказали, что костыльного в `StringBuilder`, и как в C++ все строки наследуются от единого базового класса, и как всё красиво это взаимодействует.

Comment: Для C++ такие ограничения не нужны даже сказал бы что вредны и как результат костыль StringBuilder не нужен.

Comment: @cpp_user: Вы не правы. Попробуйте, например, унаследоваться от `basic_string`, и вывести полученную строку через `cout`. Потом поговорим о костылях.

Comment: std::string это и есть basic_string<char> между прочим.